# JSON string within CSV data read by pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file where only certain parts of that file are JSON strings.  I am trying to use pandas to analyze this data.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the specific JSON strings to be shown as JSON strings, as they are contained within the CSV file.

The csv file would be something like this:

```
username,data,
name1,"very long json string",
name2,"very long json string",
```

Comment: Use a different delimiter than comma.

Comment: Does json always appear after the name variable